# Section is always off the screen at 100% width

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble with sections on a web page. My first section is floated left and the section below I am having trouble with. I have tried clearing the second section which causes the placement of it to be behind the one above. If I then use float, the sections placement works however its width is thrown off.

Image of section when cleared: [image]
Image of section when floated: [image]

```css
/* Section who */

section {
  background-color: white;
}

#who {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 45px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#who h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#who .sub_section {
}

#who #summary {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

#who #skills {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}

#who #skills .skill span {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px; 
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#who #skills .skill p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#who #skills .skill .active-skill {
  background-color: #3C7ABE;
}

#who #skills .skill .empty-skill {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
/* End of section who */

/* Section Work */

#work {
  background-color: #3C7ABE;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  clear: all;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

#work h1 {
  text-align: center;
  clear: all;
}


/* End of section work */
```

```html
  <section id="who">
    <div class="sub_section" id="summary">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_section" id="skills">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="work">
    <div class="work_item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </section>
```

I have tried to minimise the amount of code I am showing you by taking out the content in the HTML and just giving the div arrangement. All of the CSS for both sections and their contents is above. If any other info is needed just let me know, but I think that should be good enough.

Thanks

Comment: So what do you actually want to achieve here? That nothing gets displayed next to a floated element if the width is set to 100%, should be obvious. And clearing a float is _supposed_ to make the element display below the floated ones before it.

Comment: you can read about it at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to achieve? If you add both "float: left" its not missplaced on the left side. You should give the #work div box-sizing: border-box that you don't have an element 100% width + paddings.

```css
/* Section who */

section {
  background-color: white;
}

#who {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 45px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#who h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#who .sub_section {
}

#who #summary {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

#who #skills {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}

#who #skills .skill span {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px; 
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#who #skills .skill p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#who #skills .skill .active-skill {
  background-color: #3C7ABE;
}

#who #skills .skill .empty-skill {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
/* End of section who */

/* Section Work */

#work {
  background-color: #3C7ABE;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#work h1 {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}


/* End of section work */
```

```html
 <section id="who">
    <div class="sub_section" id="summary">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_section" id="skills">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="work">
    <div class="work_item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </section>
```

See on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czoyLet5/

Maybe it helps you

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly, I wanted each section to sit on top of eachother. What is  "box-sizing: border-box;" this is what I have added to my original code and works perfectly. Is there any explanation of this? Thank you for your help though

Comment: Box sizing defines which value contain inside the width of an element.
E.g: If you got an element width: 100px & padding: 0 20px; The Element have an width calculated from 140px;
If you set box-sizing: border-width, the width will be calculated within the border and paddings, that means the width of our box is still 100px in our example, but the content has only 60px space, because the padding is now inside of our element.

=> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `box-sizing: border-box;` for both of sections

```css
section {
  background-color: white;
}

#who {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 45px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#who h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#who .sub_section {
}

#who #summary {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

#who #skills {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}

#who #skills .skill span {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px; 
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#who #skills .skill p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#who #skills .skill .active-skill {
  background-color: #3C7ABE;
}

#who #skills .skill .empty-skill {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
/* End of section who */

/* Section Work */

#work {
  background-color: #3C7ABE;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  clear: all;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#work h1 {
  text-align: center;
  clear: all;
}
```

```html
<section id="who">
    <div class="sub_section" id="summary">
      <div class="content">section1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_section" id="skills">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="work">
    <div class="work_item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this has solved it but someone answered it just before you. Is there an explanation of the box-sizing stuff anywhere as I have not every heard of this before?